# Consume a list of objects from jersey endpoint

Tags: java, json, dropwizard

I have an endpoint called `"/locations"`, and i wan't to send a list of json objects to that endpoint, but when i attempt to send the post request i got an exception:

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Unable to process JSON"
}
```

Here's the code i used:

**Endpoint:**

```
@POST
@Timed
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response addLocations(@NotNull @Valid final Locations locations)
throws FreightosException {
  locationService.addLocations(locations);
  LOGGER.info("[createLocation] Successfully created!");
  return Response.accepted().build();
}
```

**Locations class:**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Locations {
  private List < Location > locations;

  public Locations(List <Location> locationsData) {
    this.locations = locationsData;
  }

  public Locations() {
    this.locations = new ArrayList <> ();
  }

  public List <Location> getLocations() {
    return locations;
  }

  public void setLocations(List <Location> locations) {
    this.locations = locations;
  }
}
```

**Location model:**

```
public class Location {
  private String ecommerceKey;

  private Country country;

  private State state;

  private Type type;

  private String value;

  private String label;


  public Location() {}
  // Setters and getters
}
```

**JSON sample:**

```
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "ecommerceKey": "#BWI2",
      "country": "US",
      "state": "ARIZONA",
      "type": "AMZ",
      "value": "2010 Broening Hwy. Baltimore, MD 21224",
      "label": "#BWI2 - 2010 Broening Hwy. Baltimore, MD 21224 - Baltimore County"
    },
    {
      "ecommerceKey": "#BWI32",
      "country": "UK",
      "state": "ARIZONA",
      "type": "UPS",
      "value": "2010 Broening Hwy. Baltimore, MD 21224",
      "label": "#BWI2 - 2010 Broening Hwy. Baltimore, MD 21224 - Baltimore County"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you have XmlRootElement on Locations?

Comment: Was trying to some workaround, but still the same, also after deleting it

Comment: You probably have an exception stack trace in your logs.

Comment: There's no stack trace, the exception i got in the response posted

Comment: If i put java 7 array and post only one element it will work, but i sent more than one element like that in the post, it won't work!

Comment: If you change the endpoint signature to ``public Response addLocations(@NotNull @Valid final List<Location> locations)`` and send the JSON array of locations do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes, still got the same error

Comment: There's very likely an exception server side explaining why it failed to deserialize. If you have your logs going to a file, be sure to check there.